# Creating list of dictionaries replaced the value of dict with the last element

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to create list of dictionary , but why it is replacing all values with 25  in all dictionary rather than 1,2,4,16,25

```
>>> cmd = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> cmd_dict = dict()
>>> cmd_new = []
>>>
>>> for i in cmd:
...     cmd_dict["hi"] = i*i
...     cmd_new.append(cmd_dict)
...
>>> cmd_new
[{'hi': 25}, {'hi': 25}, {'hi': 25}, {'hi': 25}, {'hi': 25}]
>>>
```

Comment: You need to make a new `cmd_dict` inside the loop, otherwise you keep using the same instance.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)